# Comparing elements in 2 tables efficiently

Tags: r

I would like to know if there is some built-in function that can help me efficiently execute the following algorithm.
Assume tables 1 and table 2 with `size(table 2) < size(table1)`.

For each element in table 1, I search the whole table 2 until a condition between a column from table 1 and a column from table 2 are met. Specifically I want to find the column values for c2 in table 2 that `abs(table1$c1[j]- table2$c1)<0.01 for each j.`

I have used at the moment a for loop for table1 that returns

```
 for each j        
    table2$c2[abs(table1$c1[j]- table2$c1)<0.01]
```

but this is really slow.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should provide a reproducible example.

Comment: do they have same number of rows? if so, `table2$c2[abs(table1$c1- table2$c1)<0.01]` should be fine if you want to compare row wise.

Comment: No, table 2 is much smaller than table 1

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example as @agstudy mentioned, or at least explain your task better. Your `abs` subtracts a vector from a scalar value, which is possible due to vector recycling, but it seems doubtful that this is what you intend. Is it? Second, what is "table" in your example? The `table` class in R does not allow the use of $ operator, as far as I know. Is it a data frame?

Comment: I think the bottleneck here is that the result must be a list, since the number of elements extracted from `table2$c2` may vary.

Answer (score 0):

One way to archive what you want would be to use the [sqldf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/) package. It allows you to formulate joins in SQL syntax and thus you just could use your condition above.

However, there probably is a more efficient way without the way to a database directly in R. However, if you are familiar with SQL, this could be very time efficient on the side of programming.

Without a reproducible example I am not able to give you tested code, though.

Answer (score 0):

We can perform this using data.table like this where the first column is  table2$c1 and the second column is the corresponding  table1$c1.

Here some data:

```
set.seed(123)
library(data.table)
## this replaces your table1$c1
xx <- seq(0.0,99,0.1)
## choose 6 variable and add some offset ( 0.01 and -0.01)
y  <- c(sample(xx,3) + 0.01 ,sample(xx,3) - 0.01)
```

data.table(c1 = xx, xx, key = "c1")[J(y),, 
                                    roll = 'nearest', rollends = TRUE]

Now setting option `roll` to `nearest` we get :

```
data.table(c1 = xx, xx, key = "c1")[J(y),, 
              roll = 'nearest', rollends = TRUE]
      c1   xx
1: 28.41 28.4
2: 78.01 78.0
3: 40.41 40.4
4: 87.49 87.5
5: 93.09 93.1
6:  4.49  4.5
```

The column xx  is the nearest values to table$c1. If you want to set the distance you can set roll to 0.01/-0.01 like this :

```
 data.table(c1 = xx, xx, key = "c1")[J(y),, 
                                     roll = 0.01, rollends = TRUE]
```

or

```
data.table(c1 = xx, xx, key = "c1")[J(y),, 
                                     roll = -0.01, rollends = TRUE]
```